# Regarding YouTube v3 API : Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "quotaExceeded

Tags: youtube-api

I hope this message finds you well. I am writing to seek assistance with an issue I've encountered while using the Google API (YouTube API v3).

I have been utilising the Google API for a specific project, and I recently received a "quotaExceeded" error with a 403 Forbidden status. However, when I checked my dashboard, it indicated that only approximately 280 requests had been made by my program.

As far as my understanding goes, the program should be capable of making up to 10,000 requests per day. Given the situation, I am wondering if there might be something I am overlooking or if there are any specific steps I need to take to ensure that the program can access the full quota.

Any guidance or insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Best regards,
Saleem

Comment: You're confusing with [quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota), pay attention to [each endpoint cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost).

Comment: This is a service related problem, the question is not relevant in stack overflow. Should be asked in google support

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the **type of request**, the **price** for the call to the api **changes:**

- **Search** costs **100 units**
- **Inserting items** into a **playlist** costs **50 units**
- and so on

check the **documentation** for more information:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs

My ipotesis is that you probably tried retriving 280 items by searching them 1 by 1, therefore costing you 280 * 100 = 28 000 which causes a "quotaExceeded" error.
Hope this helps